# Trouble simplifying conditional

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement

I'm having trouble simplifying a conditional statement. It looks like this:
There is an array of arrays like this, dice = [ [a, b], [c, d] ].
a, b, c, and d representing random numbers on a dice 1 > 6.
Every array in the array represents a roll of two dice where the last roll is [c, d] = [2, 5] for example, 
and the second-last roll is [a, b] = [3, 6] for example.
Now if you roll 2 x 1 in a row or 2 x 6 in a row something happens.
so,  a + c || a + d and b + c  || b + d may not be 2 or 12.
The conditional below works but I think if you open the door to hell it looks prettier.
dice = last roll = [c, d]
prev = second last roll = [a, b]

```
if (dice[0] + prev[0] === 2 || dice[1] + prev[1] === 2 || dice[1] + prev[0] === 2 || dice[0] + 
prev[1] === 2 &&
dice[0] + prev[0] === 12 || dice[1] + prev[1] === 12 || dice[1] + prev[0] === 12 || dice[0] + 
prev[1] === 12){
//something happens here
}
```

Comment: Is your question's code missing parentheses around each of the set of ORs? i.e. should it be `if ((dice[0] + prev[0] === 2 || dice[1] + prev[1] === 2 || dice[1] + prev[0] === 2 || dice[0] + 
prev[1] === 2) &&
(dice[0] + prev[0] === 12 || dice[1] + prev[1] === 12 || dice[1] + prev[0] === 12 || dice[0] + 
prev[1] === 12)) {`

Comment: You are right @BenStephens, they are present in the app itself.

Comment: I've managed to reduce the condition to 23 characters.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```js
var combinations = dice.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    return acc.concat(prev.map(function(curr2) {
        return curr + curr2;
    }));
}, []);

if (combinations.indexOf(2) !== -1 && combinations.indexOf(12) !== -1) {
    //something happens here
}
```

In ES6 it is a little bit shorter:

```js
const combinations = dice.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(prev.map(curr2 => curr + curr2)), []);

if (combinations.indexOf(2) !== -1 && combinations.indexOf(12) !== -1) {
    //something happens here
}
```

What this actually does is calculate all combinations (additions) and then check whether one is 2 and one is 12.

Comment: Very nice. The ES6 version could use `includes` instead of `indexOf`

Comment: Agreed. `indexOf` is just an oldschooled habit of me. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I came out with a simpler solution more fitted to your need

```js
const throws1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
const throws2 = [[1, 2], [3, 1]]
const throws3 = [[1, 6], [6, 1]]


const checkCondition = (prev, dice) => [1, 6].every(res => prev.includes(res) && dice.includes(res))

console.log(checkCondition(...throws1))
console.log(checkCondition(...throws2))
console.log(checkCondition(...throws3))
```

Comment: Please may you also explain the code?

Comment: @Nuod tell if you need more explanation and if that make sense

Comment: @R4ncid it's not for me, but for the OP (or any other user) who may not understand how your code works.

Comment: @R4ncid, thanks for the effort. And yes I need a deeper analysis of the code you provided.

Comment: @Noud I simplify my answer take a look

Comment: Unfortunately however this does not answer OP's question. All the possible throws that get inside OP's `if` statement are  `[[1,6],[1,6]]` or `[[6,1],[6,1]]`.

Comment: My understanding of the question makes me think that `some` should be replaced by `every` in this answer.

Comment: @BenStephens you're absolutely right. I updated the comment

Comment: @albjerto because I deleted my previous comment it now looks like you're agreeing with a comment of mine that you weren't, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The condition can only happens when both `dice` and `prev` contain 1 or 6. So, we can just check that.

```js
let throws = [[5,3],[1,6]];
let prev = throws[0];
let dice = throws[1];

if ((prev.includes(1) && dice.includes(1)) || (prev.includes(6) && dice.includes(6))){
  console.log("2 or 12 occurs")
}
else {
  console.log("2 and 12 do not occur")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like the following?:

```js
const one_and_six_found = (roll) => roll.includes(1) && roll.includes(6);
const two_rolls_have_one_and_six = (roll1, roll2) =>
  one_and_six_found(roll1) && one_and_six_found(roll2);

console.log(two_rolls_have_one_and_six( [1, 6], [1, 6] ));
console.log(two_rolls_have_one_and_six( [6, 1], [1, 6] ));
console.log(two_rolls_have_one_and_six( [5, 1], [1, 6] ));
```

Comment: I believe I managed to reduce the condition to 23 characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the conditional simplified:

```
2*(a + b + c + d) == a*b + c*d + 16
```

Comment: What if b is 2 and d is 5?

Comment: `let a = 1, b = 2, c = 6, d = 5;` :: `a % 5 + c % 5 == 2` #true :: `a + b + c + d == 14` #true :: `((a + c === 2 || b + d === 2 || b + c === 2 || a + d === 2) && (a + c === 12 || b + d === 12 || b + c === 12 || a + d === 12))` #false

Comment: Thanks! I amended the answer to address your comments. (I'm confused by what seems like someone having removed a similar comment to this that I posted here yesterday.)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't 100% sure about a couple of these answers so I thought I'd test them:

```js
const orig = ([a, b], [c, d]) =>
  ((a + c === 2 || b + d === 2 || b + c === 2 || a + d === 2) && (a + c === 12 || b + d === 12 || b + c === 12 || a + d === 12));

const A = ([a, b], [c, d]) => 2*(a + b + c + d) == a*b + c*d + 16;
const B = (prev, dice) => [1, 6].every(res => prev.includes(res) && dice.includes(res));
const one_and_six_found = (roll) => roll.includes(1) && roll.includes(6);
const C = (roll1, roll2) => one_and_six_found(roll1) && one_and_six_found(roll2);
const D = (prev, dice) => (prev.includes(1) && dice.includes(1)) || (prev.includes(6) && dice.includes(6));
const E = (prev, dice) => {
  const combinations = dice.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(prev.map(curr2 => curr + curr2)), []);

  return (combinations.indexOf(2) !== -1 && combinations.indexOf(12) !== -1);
};

const test = (fn) => {
  for(let i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    for(let j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
      for(let k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
        for(let l = 1; l <= 6; l++) 
          if(fn([i, j], [k, l]) !== orig([i, j], [k, l])) {
            console.log('failed on ' + [i, j, k, l].join(', '));
            return false;
          }
  
  return true;
};

console.log('A', test(A) ? 'success' : 'failed');
console.log('B', test(B) ? 'success' : 'failed');
console.log('C', test(C) ? 'success' : 'failed');
console.log('D', test(D) ? 'success' : 'failed');
console.log('E', test(E) ? 'success' : 'failed');
```

Comment: Ben Stephens, is test(D) failing because of the possibiltity of 4 x 1 or 4 x 6 in a row. Which is not included in the conditional.

Comment: Hi @Noud I'm not sure if this is a question or a statement (and, therefore, I've not understood the original question).

Comment: D returns true if dice and prev have 1 in them; it will also return true if dice and prev have 6 in them; it doesn't require that both of these things are true. If the `||` in D was changed to `&&` it would basically do the same as B and C.